# What is the meaning of adding backward slash at the end of the statement?

Tags: objective-c

I am using Xcode 5.1 and observed a weird syntax. I added "\" at the end of statement:

```
CGFloat x = 3.0;\
```

And to my surprise its not a syntactical error and my app is working. But if I add two slashes then it gives me error. Also I didn't see any change in my app behaviour due to this. As I am new to Objective C, I wanted to know the meaning of adding backward slash at the end of the statement.

Comment: It's simply the line continuation character. Is this not inside a macro definition by accident?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the source file is processed by the pre-processor, the backslash-newline is simply removed, so a line like:

```
CGFloat x = 3.0;\ 
CGFloat y = 4.0;
```

Becomes:

```
CGFloat x = 3.0;CGFloat y = 4.0;
```

which is still valid.  However:

```
CGFloat x = 3.0;\\
CGFloat y = 4.0;
```

which becomes:

```
CGFloat x = 3.0;\
CGFloat y = 4.0;
```

would not be valid.

See the first section of [this pretty old looking text](https://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/cpp/cpp.html).

Comment: Minor point, but….  In your final example, I think the newline wouldn't actually get removed if you looked at preprocessor output.

Answer (score 0):

You are "escaping" the new line character (return) that's at the end of the text line.  Since it's legal to have multiple statements on a line, that's OK.  If you put a second slash at the end, you're inserting a literal '\' character into your source and that's not valid syntax.

You often see the single '\' character in multi-line macros in C-like languages to make them more readable.